# Python convert.txt to .csv without having a specific file name

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I am currently working on an application that will convert a messy text file full of data into an organized CSV. It currently works well but when I convert the text file to csv I want to be able to select a text file with any name. The way my code is currently written, I have to name the file "file.txt". How do I go about this?

Here is my code. I can send the whole script if necessary. Just to note this is a function that is linked to a tkinter button. Thanks in advance.

```
def convert():
df = pd.read_csv("file.txt",delimiter=';')
df.to_csv('Cognex_Data.csv')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog

Comment: what's stopping you from writing a different file name than `file.txt` when on `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: @Mario ithe program prompts the user to select a file but if the file name hasnt been saved as "file.txt" then it wont work. I want it to run even if the file is named differently.

Comment: Are you actually using the result of the prompt as the filename in ``pd.read_csv``?

Comment: @Jenny no, thats my problem, I dont know how to actually use the prompt. I have an entry field that populates with the file path once the file has been selected but my pd.read_csv is basically just looking for the file called file.txt

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for the *input()* built-in function. You'll find it very useful. Also, a sample fragment of the input file would be interesting. *read_csv* would have to be able to decipher the file as CSV format so isn't it already a CSV (notwithstanding the filename suffix)? From the *pandas* documentation for *read_csv()* "Read a comma-separated values (csv) file into DataFrame"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining your function as follow:

```py
def convert(input_filename, output_filename='Cognex_Data.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(input_filename, delimiter=';')
    df.to_csv(output_filename)
```

And for instance use it as follow:

```py
filename = input("Enter filename: ")
convert(filename, "Cognex_Data.csv")
```

You can also put "Cognex_Data.csv" as a default value for the `output_filename` argument in the `convert` function definition (as done above).

And finally you can use any way you like to get the filename (for instance `tkinter.filedialog` as suggested by matszwecja).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with `tkinter`, but `PySimplyGUI`, which to my knowledge is built on `tkinter` so you should have the possibility to extract the variables that correspond to the name of the file selected by the user. That's what I'm doing using `PySimpleGUI`on a similar problem.

Then, extract the file name selected by the user through the prompt and pass it as an argument to your function:

```
def convert(file):
    df = pd.read_csv("{}.txt".format(file), delimiter=';')
    df.to_csv('Cognex_Data.csv')
```